# List of String Arrays overwriting itself

Tags: java, arrays, string

First ever question here, complete newbie so try to take it easy on me. I'm trying to figure out what's wrong here:

```
public List<String[]> idOnlyQuery(String searchTerm, Connection conn){

    List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] rowResult = new String[7];

    Statement stmt = null;      
    try {
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Jets WHERE CurrentID LIKE '" + searchTerm + "%'");
      while(rs.next()){

          String currentId= rs.getString("CurrentId");
          String manufacturer = rs.getString("Constructor");
          String type = rs.getString("ACType");
          String series = rs.getString("Series");
          String index = rs.getString("KeyNo");
          String operator = rs.getString("Operator");
          String baseAirport = rs.getString("Home_Airfield");
          rowResult[0] = (currentId);
          rowResult[1] = (manufacturer);
          rowResult[2] = (type);
          rowResult[3] = (series);
          rowResult[4] = (operator);
          rowResult[5] = (baseAirport);
          rowResult[6]= (index);
          result.add(rowResult);
      }
    System.out.println(result.get(0)[0]);
```

This method returns a list of string arrays, these arrays are retrieved from an SQLite database. Everything works apart from the fact that the string arrays in my result `List` seem to be getting overwritten every time the while loop repeats itself. The last `println` always gives me the `currentId` of the last row retrieved from the database, but if I put a `println` inside the `while` loop it returns the appropriate data on each while cycle. I really can't figure out where my `String[]` elements are getting overwritten. It's probably really obvious but I've spent hours looking online to check if I'm doing the add procedure correctly and still no joy. HELP!

Comment: @Batty you sir, are amazing, it works! If you don´t mind expanding on that, why is that line necessary?

Comment: It's necessary, because you need to initialize a new array before writing the informations into. You would just overwrite your current array without the initialization.

Comment: Thank you everyone! It makes sense now! I have so much to learn... You've all saved me a huge headache! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the `rowResult` array in the loop. Your list just holds a pointer to the array and you are basically only working with one instance all the time.

Answer (score 1):

in while use `rowResult = new String[7];` everytime before initializing.

This is because, arrays are objects in Java, so basically you are changing value of same object again and again.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are reassigning the array locations:

```
  rowResult[0] = (currentId);
  rowResult[1] = (manufacturer);
  rowResult[2] = (type);
  rowResult[3] = (series);
  rowResult[4] = (operator);
  rowResult[5] = (baseAirport);
  rowResult[6]= (index);
```

Create a temporary `String` array inside your while loop and add that to your `result`:

```
while (rs.next()) {
      String[] rowResult = new String[7];
      ..
      // do your stuff
      result.add(rowResult);
}
```

Every time the `while` loop executes, it will add it to `result` and you will start anew.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your rowResult object. You have to create a new one, fill it and add it to your list every iteration. What you do is like taking a basket, fill it with oranges and put it on the shelve, then take the same basket, throw the oranges out and put new ones in.

```
public List<String[]> idOnlyQuery(String searchTerm, Connection conn){

    List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    Statement stmt = null;      
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Jets WHERE CurrentID LIKE '" + searchTerm + "%'");
        while(rs.next()){
            String[] rowResult = new String[7];
            rowResult[0] = rs.getString("CurrentId");
            rowResult[1] = rs.getString("Constructor");
            rowResult[2] = rs.getString("ACType");
            rowResult[3] = rs.getString("Series");
            rowResult[4] = rs.getString("Operator");
            rowResult[5] = rs.getString("Home_Airfield");
            rowResult[6] = rs.getString("KeyNo");
            result.add(rowResult);
        }
        System.out.println(result.get(0)[0]);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same rowResult array for all rows. Put the line

```
String[] rowResult = new String[7];
```

inside the while loop, and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwritting again and again the String array. Try to create a new array in each loop.

```
List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] rowResult;

Statement stmt = null;      
try {
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Jets WHERE CurrentID LIKE '" + searchTerm + "%'");
  while(rs.next()){
     rowResult = new String[7]; //Create a new object


      String currentId= rs.getString("CurrentId");
      //...
  }
```

This is because when you are doing this:

```
rowResult = new String[7]; //Create a new object
```

This variable points out to an object in memory:

```
rowResult -------------> new String[7]
```

So if I do loop over and over the result set and write using rowResult I am indeed only modifying one object (by adding it every time to the list you only have a lot of variables pointing to the same object):

```
result.get(0) -------------->|
result.get(1)--------------->| String[7] 
result.get(n)--------------->|
```

When creating by new operator an new array in the loop you are indeed having a new fresh object to work with:

```
result.get(0) -------------->| String[7]
result.get(1)--------------->| String[7] 
result.get(n)--------------->| String[7]
```