# Why does the new element added into my ArrayList overwrite all previous values?

Tags: java, arraylist

I retrieve values from a database, create a new Transaction Object and add it to an `ArrayList<Transaction>`, which I then return.

The problem is that everytime `returnList.add(t);` is called, instead of just adding the Transaction, it also replaces all old Transactions with the new one.

Where is the error that causes this behaviour?

```
public ArrayList<Transaction> getTransactions(long intervall, Map<String, String> transactionFields) {
    connect();
    ArrayList<Transaction> returnList = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    Statement sta;
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    now = now.minusSeconds(intervall);
    try {
        sta = conn.createStatement();
        String Sql = "...";
        ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            Transaction t = new Transaction(rs.getString("No"), transactionFields);
            t.set("AgentName", rs.getString("cname"));
            returnList.add(t);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        ...
    }
    disconnect();
    return returnList;
}
```

Here is the Transaction class:

```
public class Transaction {  
private Map<String, String> fields;

public Transaction(String number, Map<String, String> transactionFields) {
    fields = transactionFields;
    fields.put("Number", number);
}

public void set(String field, String value) {
    fields.put(field, value);
}

public String get(String field) {
    return fields.get(field);
}

public Map<String, String> getFieldMap() {
  return fields;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return fields.toString();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172623/list-of-string-arrays-overwriting-itself

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger as I suspect this is not what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the same `Map` in all your `Transaction` instances.

Instead, pass in a new one each time:

```
Transaction t = new Transaction(rs.getString("No"), new HashMap<String, String>());
```

or just create the `Map` inside your `Transaction` class.

Comment: And, to complement that, if one is doing a defensive copy in the constructor, there should also be a defensive copy in the `getFieldMap()`.

Comment: Yeah just need to pass a deepcopy of the transactionFields. Thank you.